# How to add the custom cast button in option menu in android for chromecast?

Tags: android, chromecast, optionmenu

I have completed almost Chromecast integration but just i need to add the custom cast button in my option menu of the activity. How to do this?, I got null pointer exception when added the custom cast button as an item in the menu.

my Code part is:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
    .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(APP_ID)).build();

    mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback();
    mCastListener = new CastListener();
    mConnectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks();
    mConnectionFailedListener = new ConnectionFailedListener();

    // Set the MediaRouteButton selector for device discovery.
    mMediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);

}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <item android:id="@+id/share"
            android:title="Share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share" />

           <item android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:title="Feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_feedback" />

            <item android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:title="Quit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

            <android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
            android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
            android:visibility="gone" />
           </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

For MediaRouteButton your activity needs to extend FragmentActivity

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have extended the FragmentActivity but still getting Null pointer exception for mMediaRouteButton

Comment: Take a look at this sample app on how to correctly add the button: https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

Comment: I have already look up on that where they used cast button separately in layout view , But i just need to add the cast button in option menu as one of the item so pls give some idea for that.

Comment: The Cast Design Checklist requires the Cast button to be displayed on the top level of the action bar.

Comment: Yes i have seen that checklist and everybody mostly displayed on the action bar. So is there any possibilities to display the custom cast button in option menu?